# Multiple like buttons on blog page acting as one button despite separate anchor names

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-iframe

I have added facebook like buttons to each entry on my blog - although I have given each entry it's own URL by including an anchor name, clicking Like on one adds to the like count of all of them.  Any advice on how to sort this?

An example of the code is:

Answer (score 1):

Well my initial guess is that Facebook ignores the anchor. You could try passing a parameter, e.g.
www.example.com/myblog.html?entry=1#entry1
www.example.com/myblog.html?entry=2#entry2

Good luck

Comment: thank you - I'm unfortunately very basic and not set up to use php: any (extremely) lower tech solutions would be greatly appreciated!